# spacemacs: how to define a new key-binding with a leading [SPC]?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I would like to bind a set of additional keys for spacemacs. The following statement is used:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "SPC-1") '(fzf/start "01-personal"))
```

yet it does not work that Emacs complains that `SPC` is not a prefix key. Just wonder how spacemacs is able to do it. Did some searches, but didn't find the information for it. Can anyone help?

Comment: For one thing, `(kbd "SPC-1")` won't do anything useful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A more complete answer, is to first declare a prefix, and then set leader keys. For example:

```
 (spacemacs/declare-prefix "o" "own-menu")
 (spacemacs/set-leader-keys "os" 'ispell-buffer)
```

Using "o" as a prefix is a good idea, as it is guaranteed to be available for customization. Other prefixes might be used by different layers.

You can also add nested prefixes, for example I use the following to work with IDs in orgmode:

```
 ;; org-ids
 (spacemacs/declare-prefix "od" "id")
 (spacemacs/set-leader-keys "odc" 'org-id-copy)
 (spacemacs/set-leader-keys "odu" 'org-id-update-id-locations)
```

Which allows me to press `SPC o d c` to copy an Org header id (and create one if it doesn't already exist).

Comment: For mode-specific prefix key: `(spacemacs/declare-prefix-for-mode 'mode "p" "prefix name")`.

Comment: For mode-specific leader key: `(spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-major-mode 'mode "pl" 'function)`.

Comment: Partially documented [here](https://www.spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html#binding-keys).

Answer (score 3):

Just did some further search, the right way to set such keybinding under spacemacs is:

```
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "1" 'keymap)
```

Comment: What is keymap here?